# Fullcalendar - adding custom fields to renderEvent

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

hope someone can help me out with this.

I am using the Fullcalendar js event calendar. 
Currently loading the events as below :

```
events: "workshopview/functions.php?act=loadAllEvents",
```

Here is the content of the loadAllEvents script

```
while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    $events[] = array (
        'start' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($row['event_start'])),
        'end' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($row['event_end'])),
        'title' => $row['reg_no'],
        'job_type'=>$row['job_type'],
        'id'=>$row['booking_id'],
        'color'=>$row['event_color'],
        'job_status'=>$row['event_status'],
        'service_advisor'=>$row['service_advisor'],
        );
}
```

Now my problem, when i try to call the last field, "service_advisor", it is not rendering onto the calendar view, but the rest of the fields work

Below is the code i am using to render the fields :

```
eventRender: function(event, element){ 
    element.find('.fc-title').append("<br/>" + event.job_type); 
},
```

So, when i try to use event.service_advisor, instead of the other fields, it is not getting displayed

What am I doing wrong? Some help will be much appreciated

Comment: There's no obvious reason it wouldn't work. What type of data is it? Are you certain the field is actually populated in the events you're using to test with? See working example at http://jsfiddle.net/toytd26b/72/ (random raw data at http://myjson.com/ydkgy) - in theory the field would be displayed. I think it's more likely that your event data doesn't contain what you think it does. You can easily find out by checking the output of your PHP script separately, or watching the ajax request to it in your Network tools in the browser when fullCalendar is loading and viewing the response.

Comment: Well I have checked the event data, if I just run the php function, it does return the desired results, only in eventRender it's not displaying any values

Comment: Ok, so firstly please show exactly how you're using event.service_advisor in your eventRender code, you haven't actually shown us the version which is not working. And please also give an example of your event JSON including this field. Did you check out my JSFiddle example? You can see that it definitely works if you a) have a value in your data for that field, and b) add the field to the element in a suitable way. Unfortunately those two things - i.e. the most important details - are the only bits of information you haven't shared.